# Angular Http vs. HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I am working on a angular 6+ project that in some of its parts uses angular http services to make some api calls to the server and I try to convert these http services to the new httpClient service.

But I got strange error that I have not any idea on the error. The attempting part is below. Could you help me with it?

**The working http example:**

This example works fine and getting response properly

```
public userLogin(userData: LoginModel): Promise<any> {
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        })
    });
    const model: LoginRequestModel = {
        EncryptedUsername: this.helper.encrypt(userData.UserName),
        EncryptedPassword: this.helper.encrypt(userData.Password),
        Stamp: ""
    }
    let data = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this.http.post(this.api + "login", data, options).toPromise();
}
```

**The not working httpClient example:**

I got an error on the console;

```
userLogin2(userData: LoginModel): Observable<any> {
    let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        })
    };

    const model: LoginRequestModel = {
        EncryptedUsername: this.helper.encrypt(userData.UserName),
        EncryptedPassword: this.helper.encrypt(userData.Password),
        Stamp: ""
    }

    let data = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.api + "login", data, options);
}
```

and the error:

```
body: {error: "Collection 'v1' not found"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "https://converting.azurewebsites.net/api/v1.0/login"
```

Comment: Is the url `https://converting.azurewebsites.net/api/v1.0/login` valid? Did the version change?

Comment: For the security issue I mask the url but yeah it is valid and I can get response properly when I use old fashion angular http

Comment: Couple things to try: don't stringify the model, send it as an object; don't send the options, the HttpClient sends requests as json by default.

Comment: Thanks to your comments R. Richards. I just try your suggestions before and the example I provide my last attempt. I just try send the req without option and without stringfy the model with no luck and got the same error.

Comment: you can seen:http://hoanguyenit.com/login-state-in-angular-7.html or http://hoanguyenit.com/login-state-in-angular-7-+-laravel-5-4.html . Login in Angular

Comment: Another thing to try is use an interface, or class, to type what you get from the post call, rather than just using `<any>`.

Comment: I made a login response interface to get rid of any and try with this model without any luck. @skipperhoa I'll try to figure out your example. thanks to both of you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to **`Angular InMemoryWebApi`**

If you have use this mock service in your project, It is re-route your actual requests and cause the `404 not found` error. For the solution you have to comment out your internal web api lines from your `app.module.ts file`

Comment: Instead of writing an answer, accept the duplicate suggested to you if it helped you.

Comment: Actually I did not see the duplicate answer and solve it by myself, but as you find the duplicate one, I accept it with a pleasure. Thanks to all of your helps.